# MySql: Some queries produce: SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

I've just moved applications to a replicated database and for some, but not all, queries I get the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user
```

Many other queries work and reviewing the credentials are indeed correct as they work for most queries.

Any ideas what might be causing this error message, given that most queries are successful?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer:

The "tables" that were being queried and failing were in fact views.

The views had been created with

```
CREATE DEFINER="user"@"10.10.%.%" SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW view_name ...
```

After changing the application to the other replicated database, the DEFINER didn't exist with the same host on this new database the user was "user"@"10.20.%.%" instead of "user"@"10.10.%.%"

So the definer didn't exist in this database, AND because the SQL SECURITY was set to DEFINER, the view could not be accessed.

In this case, I re-created the view with a different user and set the security to

```
... SQL SECURITY INVOKER ...
```

which in my db permission scheme environment the invoker will have adequate rights, so now all queries work.

Comment: Thank you, I had the exact same odd problem. After reading this I recreated the views and everything was fine again.

Comment: Thank you. Recreating the view solved my problem too.

Comment: One note, it seems that users defined when creating a view are also propagated on dumps (even if the user will not exist on the db the dump will be restored on). Make sure you identify the user defined as "definer" for your views using `SHOW CREATE VIEW your_view_name_here;`. Then, drop the view and recreate it by replacing the definer with a user that exists on your database (like explained in the @jeffRichards answer).

Comment: Are there any security concerns using INVOKER ?

Comment: @Datadimension I don't see a security concern here.  Generally, biggest "gotcha" with INVOKER security is that they may not have *enough* permissions to run the view.  With INVOKER, the user is required to have the all the necessary permissions to be able to run the underlying queries themselves.  So I would suggest that INVOKER is at least as *secure*, however, I can see the value of using DEFINER, as it's more convenient and predictable who will be able to use the view.